# Guardar el mismo ID en dos tablas diferentes Laravel

Tags: laravel

Necesito guardar el mismo ID en ambas tablas,
Tengo 2 tablas, User (de laravel auth) y Artistas

El admin solo se registra en User
Pero cuando registro a un Artista se guarda en User y Artista pero no se guarda el mismo ID

```
User
id | name 
----------
1  | admin
2  | artista1

Artista
id | name
---------
1  | artista1
```

Pero necesito que en Artista se guarde el mismo id que en User

que quede asi

```
User
id | name 
----------
1  | admin
2  | artista1

Artista
id |name
---------
2  | artista1
```

Este es mi controller

```
$user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        
            ]);

            $user->assignRole('artista');
            $artista = Artista::create([
                 'id'->$user->id,
                'name' => $request->name,
            ]);
```

estas son mi tablas

USERS

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Artista

```
 Schema::create('artistas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Tus llaves son pk y auto increment?

Comment: Ya puse las tablas en la publicacion y si se incrementan

Comment: Me parece que ahí existe un error de diseño, ¿por qué un artista debe existir en 2 tablas?, la información en una base de datos no debe estar duplicada

Comment: Lo mismo que dice BetaM, creo que estas planteando mal tu BBDD, pero colocarlo en fillable te debe permitir modificarlo. Igual revisa como planteas tus relaciones.

Comment: Solo puse como ejemplo el campo name, pero solo necesito tener las mismas id en ambas tablas

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, lo logre resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar fillable el array en tu modelo, o seguirá guardando en forma auto-incrementable.

```
protected $fillable = [
'id'
];
```

De esta manera laravel te permitirá modificarlo a tu manera.